# C# Dragdrop events not working

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

i created a little form in C# and registered some drag drop events to it. But i cant get it to work properly!

Goal: Dragging files from explorer.exe into the form, and handeling it, and photos dragged into the form. I test the code by dragging a .txt file from my desktop into the form. It shows the (/) cursor when doing so

Code:

```
public partial class Viewer : Form
{
    public Viewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Viewer_DragEnter);
        this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Viewer_DragDrop);
    }
    public void Viewer_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Viewer_DragEnter");// Line has breakpoint
    }
    public void Viewer_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Viewer_DragDrop: "+e.Data.GetFormats());// Line has breakpoint
    }
}
```

What i have tried:

Try-catch over the constructor => nothing

Running succesfull build outside of visualstudio(2010)

Running explorer.exe as administrator when dragging items into the form

Thanks for reading my question

EDIT:
when testing the files were on the desktop(%userprofile%\Desktop). but it shouldnt matter where they are stored. the images are supposed to be dragged from the browser or a word document into the form

ANOTHER EDIT:
When trying to run it without visual studio, i get an InvalidOperationException, that occurs on the AllowDrop = true; but i dont get a reaction when try-catching it

SOLUTION:
OMG... so.... i kinda moved the public static Main() into the viewer.cs file.... and i forgot to add the STAThread attribute.
I found this when executing the build outside of visual studio again, and in the exception form it showed that the thread needed to be a STAThread but that part of the message was hidden and hard to find

anyway: ALWAYS USE STATHREAD :P

Comment: There is a fair chance that DragDrop in OS itself can fail sometime. It won't work in any process. I've experienced it before. Try restarting the machine and try again.

Comment: Nope, after reboot it still didnt work

Comment: Whether is it working in all other applications?

Comment: It is, visual studio itself is able to